# JMeter - Allow simple sumbit of request (or any Sampler)

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter to execute you must create and run Thread Group with configuration and other elements, also for newbies reading the [getting started](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) can be a bit too much information.

In Postman (or curl) you can just enter request details and submit

In Blazemeter you can [Creating a URL/API Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732829-Creating-a-URL-API-Test) similarly.

I suggest to add a button as Submit/Send in HTTP request (Or Sampler) that will send the Request as is (optional loading variables/properties)

Another option is to have a default basic jmx that get URL and submit it, but it's not a full solution.

Is it a valid enhancement to JMeter or am I missing other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is nice and you created an enhancement request for it:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61805

The best way to implement it in JMeter will be to enhance the template mechanism to allow it to use parameter entered by users.

If you feel like providing a patch, have a look at TemplateManager class.