# How to run Postman tests in Jmeter? ; How to run single sampler inside a Test Plan/ Thread group when you have multiple sampler inside it?

Tags: testing, jmeter, postman, performance-testing

I have a collection in Postman under which I have multiple Requests(see screenshot 1).
[image: Screenshot1]

I can click on each request, press "send" and run one at a time. I exported the .json to .jmx from [loadium](https://loadium.io/)

When I open the the .jmx file in Jmeter , I got this kind of structure(see screenshot2).
[image: Screenshot 2]

**Test plan --> Thread group --> [Sampler 1, Sampler 2, ..]**
These samplers are my each request and I want to run only one at a time, but when I press "run" button all the sampler/requests start to run.

Comment: About your second question I asked before similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448802/jmeter-allow-simple-sumbit-of-request-or-any-sampler

Answer (score 0):

Double check your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings, if you want to run requests sequentially and only one at a time make sure to set:

- 1 thread (virtual user)
- 1 loop (iteration)

[image]

Also be aware that you don't need any external tools in order to convert Postman scripts to JMeter:

1. [Set Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)

   [image]
2. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

   [image]
3. Run your collection in Postman
4. JMeter will capture the requests and generate appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your issue is straightforward: just right-click on the script you do not want to run and select "Disable".

When you want to run it, simply right click and choose "Enable".